# .aspx files with both HTML and C# code in ASP.NET MVC - is it correct?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

So I've decided to try out ASP.NET MVC, having almost no prior experience in any kind of web development. I've created a MVC 2.0 project in Visual Studio and I see there are a couple of different .aspx pages included. They seem to mix both code and HTML:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.") %>
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Account Information</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
                <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            </div>
            ...
```

Is this standard practice? Or should I totally separate HTML and code?

Thanks

Comment: Contrary to standards, I am of the opinion that it should not be. It is the only thing that makes .NET MVC unappealing to me. It's messy. And makes the file unreadable. I've been looking for a framework that doesn't do this. And if I can't find one. I will build one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is absolutely standard practice.  That old notion of completely abolishing programming logic (even **presentation** logic) from views is a residue of history.

Comment: I am curious about this. Why the shift in mentality, then?

Comment: Because the original idea was derived from ideological maxims, rather than actually trying to solve problems in the real world.  (Or to put it another way, we, as an industry, tried it (total separation) out and found it wanting.)

Comment: Spot on Kirk. Web Forms, and their idea of total code/html separation was an ideal. In practice, I can't count the number of times my 'clean coding' turned into a vicious hack-job because I tried to follow the maxim of separation. Anything from building a custom data grid, to simply needing C# variables accessibly to the front end. It rapidly tended to slide into a mess of AJAX calls and page posts.

Comment: Indeed, the attempt at separation done in the WebForms paradigm turned out to be the wrong separation.  By trying to separate "display" from "display logic" what ended up happening was the display logic would become full of workarounds and invited tight-coupling with other layers that _should_ have been separated.

Comment: Code and HTML should be separate. Save yourself some headaches and eyestrain. Just imagine putting code in a an XML/Text/Word/INI file.

Comment: @b01, evidently you don't have the foggiest idea what you are talking about when it comes to ASP.NET/MVC.  Regardless of whether you think your notion is philosphically correct, the fact remains that this is *standard practice* in ASP.NET/MVC, which is what the OP is asking about.  Furthermore, judging by your profile, you literally do *not* know anything about this technology.  Please save your (down) votes for areas in which you actually have some expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is common practice with ASP.NET MVC views.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard in ASP .NET MVC.  This code specifically is HTML helper extensions which are supposed to be placed inline in the markup like that.  Their specific purpose is to render markup based on how you use them.

Note that the idea that this code/markup mix is a bit unwieldy is a driving force behind the [Razor view engine](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) for ASP .NET MVC, which is a little cleaner and more expressive within the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard practice. MVC projects uses views, models and controllers. Some code does have to be put into the view to handle the output of dynamic content. Unlike webforms, they do not use a codebehind. Only display code should be in the view. More complex processing should be in the model or the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just make sure that the code is all centered around creating a `View` (html) based on your `Model`. If you have code in here that goes to a repository to get data out, that code should reside in the Controller, and populate the Model with the data that your View needs to display.